# Should I add vendor/bundle to .gitignore, so it will not be added to my repository after deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

I know that `bundle install --deployment` should be run only on production server.

Should I add "vendor/bundle" to .gitignore?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to as it should be symlinked on deployment to a shared directory. More details in the deployment sub-section of this blog post http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/26/whats-new-in-bundler-1-0-0-rc-1/